# How can I apply numberSuffix on value only for fusionchart gauge chart

Tags: fusioncharts

[image]

I am using unicode arrow at the value using the chart's numberSuffix. This effects all the numbers on the chart. Is there a way to just apply it only on the value?

I did use annotations before trying this out but scaling messes up with the arrow placement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found another way of implementing the above mentioned feature.
A small hack into the code.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcvnswx2/) link.

Although accessing internal objects for implementation is not supported by FusionCharts as it is subjected to change.

```
    FusionCharts.addEventListener('rendered', function(e) {
        var dataset = e.sender.jsVars.instanceAPI.components.dataset[0],
        labelEle = dataset.graphics.dataLabel && dataset.graphics.dataLabel[0];

        labelEle && (labelEle.attr({
            text: labelEle.attrs.text + " ↓"
        }));
    });
```

Comment: thanks! I prefer this over annotations which I am currently using. The problem in my case is that I don't have a set start size for the chart so it's a bit more awkward to put in the scale details for a proper annotation.

Comment: @zam3858 You are welcome but accessing internal objects is not officially supported by **FusionCharts** as the object structure is subjected to change. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use annotations for this requirement.

Here is a workaround.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp4699wk/)

```
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```